# google map API 3.0 in print friendly mode

Tags: google-maps, printing

I print google map with satellite mode in my page using google map api 3.0. now can i printed window of google map in print firenldy mode. i dont have any idea for this !!!

google map load in :

```
<div id="mapdiv"></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything specific to the google maps that would affect the print style?

Assuming no, I think you want to look into CSS media queries and define styles for print mode.  I would guess you want to do things like hide navigation elements and perhaps make the map div bigger.

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: i need to print window of google map in click not in other page with css media !!!